# Tensorflow: How to convert float32 to uint8

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

**Here is the code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf

raw_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile("0.png", "rb").read()
image = tf.image.decode_png(raw_data)
image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [28, 28], 0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(image)

    tf.cast(image, tf.uint8)
    print(image)

    tf.bitcast(tf.cast(image, dtype=tf.int8), tf.uint8)
    print(image)
```

**Output:**

```
Tensor("resize_images/Squeeze:0", shape=(28, 28, ?), dtype=float32)
Tensor("resize_images/Squeeze:0", shape=(28, 28, ?), dtype=float32)
Tensor("resize_images/Squeeze:0", shape=(28, 28, ?), dtype=float32)
```

I'm wondering why I can't convert float32 to uint8 and how to correct the code.

Comment: You don't seem to run your code within the session. For example, when trying to print the image, you have to use print(sess.run(image)). Same applies to the other tf operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tf.cast doesn't convert the data in-place; it returns the new data, and you have to assign that to a variable or use it directly.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(image)

    image2 = tf.cast(image, tf.uint8)
    print(image2)

    image3 = tf.bitcast(tf.cast(image, dtype=tf.int8), tf.uint8)
    print(image3)
```